# How to make a staggered grid in flutter which dynamically scales it's children

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have a list of images which I would like to show in a staggered grid widget. I would like for them to scale themselves like in telegram.

[image]

I'm not entirely sure it's possible, or rather, practical to do, so if there could only be a single placement algorithm, that would work too. I can't lay them out one by one, since it's the user who chooses how many images to pick, so I have to go through a list of images and convert them into StaggeredGridTiles. I thought about giving spacing to the tiles randomly, but that didn't really work out.

```
final List<File> imageList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        StaggeredGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: _generateImages(),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: ColorName.white,
            ),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.mode_edit_outline_outlined,
              size: 16,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _generateImages() {
    final tileList = <StaggeredGridTile>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      final crossCount = Random().nextInt(1) + 1;
      final mainCount = Random().nextInt(2) + 1;

      final tile = StaggeredGridTile.count(
        crossAxisCellCount: crossCount,
        mainAxisCellCount: mainCount,
        child: Image.file(imageList[i]),
      );

      tileList.add(tile);
    }

    return tileList;
  }
```

So how can I create something similar to how telegram albums look? The only solution I have is to create some sort of constant lists with fixed numbers for each number of images the user provides.